# Why does my Boolean throw null pointer exception when I add items into FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I add items into the FirebaseDatabase like this

```
String key = mDairyDataBase.push().getKey();
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("Name", item);
dataMap.put("Key", key);
mDairyDataBase.child(key).setValue(dataMap);
mDairyDataBase.child(key).child("IsSelected").setValue(false);
```

It crashes my app and says the error is here

```
HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if(value != null){
                String name = value.get("Name");
                String key = value.get("Key");
                boolean isSelected = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child("IsSelected").getValue();
                mModelList.add(new Model(name, key, isSelected));

            }
```

but I can't seem to figure out why. It gives me a null pointer exception warning here `(Boolean) dataSnapshot.child("IsSelected").getValue();` but when my app launches again items are added and in the Database my value has a boolean value of false. I usually write an if statements for these warning but I can't seem to figure out how to write it for this one.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a Hashmap rather than your own Java classes?

Comment: @cricket_007not really just used to it

Comment: Okay, well, you can get around around the error using `Boolean isSelected =` instead, but you would still need to figure out why it's null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code, you are checking if there is an object or not in the response, you are not checking if the object has a value IsSelected.
Use this code:

```
HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if(value != null){
            String name = value.get("Name");
            String key = value.get("Key");
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("IsSelected")){
                boolean isSelected = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child("IsSelected").getValue();
            }
            mModelList.add(new Model(name, key, isSelected));

        }
```